# How can I remotely control individual baseboard heaters?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, heater

I have a vacation home that sits over winter with electric baseboard heating.  When the summer season starts up I want to be able to make sure the baseboard heating is turned off via the breaker so renters can't have the heat on and AC (has happened numerous times).  I looked into wifi thermostats but to replace the ones in each room is very expensive as the baseboard thermostats are way more then the regular furnace ones.  If I could just have a way to turn breaker on/off remotely that would work perfect or any other ideas.

Comment: *Remote* makes this difficult/expensive. Have the local management company (or yourself if you don't use one) apply a lockout to the breakers when it's "Spring" and remove them when it's "Fall" (or beginning/end of "Summer" depending on climate in the location.) Changing to a mini-split sytem that does both would also solve this, as it only does one of the two things at one time.

Comment: you would need good WiFi in your home for that to work. What is powering the baseboard heaters

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first key is to find an appropriate way of controlling the baseboard heaters by a low-voltage source. A favorite set of tools for this are the Functional Devices "Relay-in-a-Box" products (I have no affiliation with this company). Surely one of their RIB- products will have appropriate ratings to control line voltage power to the baseboard heaters and will also have a low-voltage side that can work with common DC voltage like 5v and 12v, and with the common AC 24v.

With that control "gateway" in place there is a whole world of possibilities. Here are just two:

- Use heating/cooling combo thermostats; wire the RIB to the W terminal and the air conditioner to the Y terminal. The thermostat will already have logic to prevent simultaneous heating and cooling. These could be WiFi or normal thermostats -- it sounds like your biggest goal is to avoid energy waste, not necessarily remote control of the indoor temperature.
- Or, wire the RIB back at the circuit breaker panel as a kind of low-voltage-controlled disconnect. This is the functionality requested in your question. The low voltage side of the RIB could be operated by, for example, a wall-wart power supply plugged into a WiFi-controlled outlet.

A "contactor" is a good alternative to the RIB products. It could be utilized in the same way. These are routinely used for switching currents of 40 amps and beyond in air conditioners and other things, and they're frequently controlled by a simple 24 volt AC signal.

Comment: Main caveat with contactors is that you need to get a UL 508 *listed* contactor for standalone service ("definite purpose" contactors, such as HVAC contactors, aren't legal to use outside of Listed equipment)